# Give an example of a 2x2 matrix such that the operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I do the following problem

Give an example of a 2x2 matix such that the operator norm of the product is less than the product of the operator norms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try a case where the product is $0$.